# Checking if there is an exception coming from the server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET web application written in vb.net. I have uploaded the application on a web server in the wwroot folder and once I type in the URL with a `QueryString`, on `page_Load` it should request that `QueryString` and store it in the database once in `Table1` and another in `Table2`. Well it is inserting the `QueryString` to `Table 1` but not to `Table2`. The insertion code is within a `Try Catch` block but the problem is that I have no idea how to display a server `MsgBox` with the exception  on the client-side.

I have also tried writing a `txtFile` containing any `ex.message` on the WebServer itself, but with no luck, even without an exception firing, the `txtFile` is not created I guess its a path issue. Whether to write the physical path or virtual path both tested without luck.

I am really desperate to know in anyway possible why its inserting the `QueryString` to `Table1` and not `Table2`.

I am using a `class.vb` to insert the `Querystring`. On the main page, I request the `QueryString` which is a variable (changing) table name `(Table2)`, pass it to a function defined in `class.vb` and then apply an `Insert` statement for a predefined un-changing table `(Table1)` and also using the retrieved `QueryString` `(Table2)` name to insert a date and time to both tables.

**On MainPage.aspx:**

```
Dim classOBJ AS new Projet.class1

classOBJ.Fun(Request.QueryString("Table"))
```

**In Class1.vb:**

```
 Public Sub Fun(ByVal value As String)

    Dim date_T As Date = Date.Today

    Try

    Using myconn As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
    myconn.Open()

Dim cmd1 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 (Date_T,Time_T) values (@paramdate, @paramtime)", myconn)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramdate", date_T)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramtime", Now().ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd1.Dispose()

Dim cmd2 = New SqlCommand("Insert into [" & value & "] (Date_T, Time_T) values (@paramdate, @paramtime)", myconn)

    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramdate", date_T)
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramtime", Now().ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd2.Dispose()
    myconn.Close()
    End Using
```

I am using this notation `[` `]` because `Table's 2` name is a number.

Comment: Does your second table exist?  If you're seeing the data get written to Table1 and not to the second table, then there's something wrong with the second SQL statement.  Can you check what the value of `value` is that your `Fun` method is getting?

Comment: @DavidHoerster Well yes, the second table exist because before the execution of the code above, I have a check process to check whether the `QueryString` retrieved which is `Table2`  already exists in the database. If yes, process the code above otherwise exit. I tested the code above on the localhost with no problems.

Comment: A few questions: If your database is a SQL Server, can you turn on SQL Profiler and see if you see the query being sent in?  Also, are you able to execute the SQL of your command directly against your database?  Is the second table created within the same schema (e.g. dbo) as Table1?  If not, does the user you're connecting as have access to that schema?

Comment: Are you able to execute the SQL of your command directly against your database? YES. Is the second table created within the same schema (e.g. dbo) as Table1? YES. I re-uploaded the whole application again, and it worked. My guess is because there was a mistake in referencing the `.js` file which gets the `QueryString` and write it to `MainPage.aspx` where I request it `Request.QueryString`. Really appreciate your support, thanks.